# Using an SPMetal entity class

Tags: linq, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm executing the code below to get information about a page via [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query). It works fine, but how do I convert this and using the entity class generated by the [SPMetal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538255.aspx) command?

```
Guid siteGuid = SPContext.Current.Site.ID;
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteGuid))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList lespages = web.Lists["Pages"];

        var resultat = from SPListItem page
                       in lespages.Items
                       where page.ContentType.Name.Equals("PageNews") && page.ModerationInformation.Status.Equals(SPModerationStatusType.Approved)
                       select page;

        foreach (SPListItem r in resultat)
        {
            contenu += "_ModerationStatus: " + r["_ModerationStatus"] + "<br>";
            contenu += "FileLeafRef: " + r["FileLeafRef"] + "<br>";
            contenu += "PublishingPageContent: " + r["PublishingPageContent"] + "<br>";
            contenu += "ContentType: " + r["ContentType"] + "<br>";
            contenu += "Categorie: " + r["Categorie"] + "<br>";
        }
        PanelResultat.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(contenu));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following links that will be a help for you

[1.SP Metal Code](http://www.spdavid.com/post/2010/02/18/Using-SPMetal-to-gernerate-code-for-a-specific-List.aspx)

[2. SPMetal Tutorial](http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2010/02/19/sp-2010-getting-started-with-linq-to-sharepoint-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

Comment: thx i dont have problem in generating SP Metal Code or geting data from a list, my problem is to get page field like PublishingPageContent, FileLeafRef ...